# Datetime query param changes format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am making a request to get some data using startDateTime and endDateTime query params like the following:

```
http://localhost:5000/buildings/entries?startDateTime=2020-11-01T12:00&endDateTime=2020-09-02T12:00
```

This requests goes to the API Gateway microservice which has an endpoint like the following:

```
       [HttpGet("entries")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> GetBuildingsEntries(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int? pageIndex, int? pageSize)
       {
          // Construct the query string and send a request to the buildings microservice
       }
```

The same endpoint as in above exists also in the buildings microservice however the above dates
when reaching the buildings microserve get changed from **2020-11-01T12:00 2020-09-02T12:00** to **2020-01-11T12:00 2020-02-09T12:00**.

So basically the month and the day change their places.

I know I can avoid this if I use timestamps(harder to work with), or expect them as string and cast later(ugly), but does someone knows any better solution using Datetime-s or any opinion which is the best solution ?

Comment: `2020-11-01T12:00` is in ISO8601 format. The day and month should never be switched by anything reading this value. Either this is not the actual value being sent *or* perhaps you are reading the code wrong somewhere. I recommend you try to create an [mcve].

Comment: It was just the date in this format: 2020-11-01

Comment: Try to use `datetime1.ToString("o")` when you are serializing you `DateTime`. It will serialize to `ISO8601` format.

Comment: So ur suggesting that the issue is how the clients send the date and not on the backend?

Comment: Is the client code under your source control or is it called publicly by outside entities (like an open api)? If it is under your source control start checking your code to ensure that the dates are sent correctly. If it is a customer then you need to provide documentation that explains the expected format should always be ISO8601.